# how to navigate into activity using webview in android

Tags: android, android-webview

I am doing one app. In this I am  passing **html** file using `WebView` it is working good. But in html page I have some links. When I click that link means it is default going to website. But when I click that time no need to go to website. I need to go some activity like `OnlineQuery.java`. But I dnt knw how to move  to that java file. any one knows please help me.

**Java file**:

```
public class DrugOffences extends Activity {
            WebView mWebView;
             @Override
          public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.about);
            WebView mWebView = null;
            mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            mWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Drug.html"); 


                      }
               }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set a [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) to your [webview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setWebViewClient%28android.webkit.WebViewClient%29) and override [shouldOverrideUrlLoading](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29). Check if the url to be loaded is the one you want to intercept. If it is do what you want and return true, if its not, return false.

```
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {           
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.equals("theURLYouDontWantToLoadInBrowser")) { 
            //Do your thing 
            startActivity(new Intent(this, OnlineQuery.class));
            return true;
        } else { 
            return false;          
        }       
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand at all your question, but if what you want is to handle the url navigation of the html load in the java code (webview), you could implement shouldOverrideUrlLoading (in this method you can intercept the url loadings) function.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    startActivity(intent);
```