# How can we navigate to activity from web page button click event?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have two buttons in webview. I want to give manually click events to their.
Below is my code;

**WebPage Code**

```
<form method="post" name="refer_now">
    <div class="refer-now-button">
      <!-- <button type="submit" class="refer-now-btn" id="refer-now">refer now</button> -->
      <input type="button" class="refer-now-btn" value="refer now" name="refernow" id="refernow" onClick="showAndroidToast('refer');" />
    </div>
  </form>

  <form method="post" name="refer_now_footer">
    <div class="refer-now-button">
      <!-- <button type="submit" class="refer-now-btn" id="refer_now_footer">refer now</button> -->
       <input type="button" class="refer-now-btn" value="refer now" name="refer-footer" id="refer-footer" onClick="showAndroidToast('bottom_refer');" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Below is my java code;

```
   mWebview.loadUrl(link);

            mWebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                @Override
                public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
                    //Required functionality here
                    return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
                }});
            mWebview.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "AndroidInterface");
            mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebview.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
            mWebview.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

    public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    // Instantiate the interface and set the context
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showevent(String toast) {
        if(toast.equalsIgnoreCase("refer")){
            Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else if(toast.equalsIgnoreCase("bottom_refer")){
            Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code; this gives me below errors:

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: AndroidInterface is not defined",

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to perform a button click inside a Webview Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30113445/how-to-perform-a-button-click-inside-a-webview-android)

Comment: @Mr.vicky this is not duplicate answer. I want to give multiple buttons click event. If you can give me better solution then it will helpful for me

Comment: please check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform button click from webview in android:

**HTML & Java script**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<input type="button"  value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('OK')" />
<input type="button"  value="hello mr.vicky" onClick="showAndroidToast('MR.VICKY')" />
<br/><br/>

<script type="text/javascript">
        <!-- Sending value to Android -->
        function showAndroidToast(toast) {
            AndroidInterface.showToast(toast);
        }
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JAVA code**

```
package com.ellvar.Activity.Common.Activity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.JsResult;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.ellvar.CustomView.CustomDialog;
import com.ellvar.CustomView.CustomProgressDialog;
import com.ellvar.R;
import com.ellvar.Utils.Utility;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.OnClick;

public class TermsConditionActivitydemo extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.wv_termscondition)
    WebView wvTermscondition;
    @BindView(R.id.iv_back)
    ImageView ivBack;
    CustomProgressDialog progressDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_terms_condition);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        if (!Utility.getInstance().isNetworkAvailable(this)) {
            CustomDialog.getInstance().showalert(this, getString(R.string.please_check_internet_connection));
        }else{
            loaddata();
        }
    }
    private void loaddata() {
        wvTermscondition.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
        wvTermscondition.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                                  @Override
                                  public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
                                      //Required functionality here
                                      return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
                                  }});
        wvTermscondition.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "AndroidInterface");
        wvTermscondition.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wvTermscondition.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        wvTermscondition.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    }


    @OnClick(R.id.iv_back)
    public void onViewClicked() {
        finish();
    }


    public class WebAppInterface {
        Context mContext;

        // Instantiate the interface and set the context
        WebAppInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void showToast(String toast) {
            if(toast.equalsIgnoreCase("OK")){
                Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(toast.equalsIgnoreCase("MR.VICKY")){
                Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }


}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Hii I got error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: AndroidInterface is not defined"

Comment: What does this say?

Comment: I took all referrence from your code still got same error

Comment: Please try to create new project and just past this two files because i have done it successfully and uploaded output also.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure If you can call `addJavaScriptInterface` method multiple times with different `names`. Try moving your `performClick1` method under same `JavaScriptInterface` like:

```
    view.addJavascriptInterface(new Object() {
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void performClick() {
            Intent i = new Intent(FollowPageActivity.this, MyLoyaltyActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void performClick1() {
            Intent i = new Intent(FollowPageActivity.this, MyLoyaltyActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }, "refer_now");// identify which button you click
```

Comment: Can you tell me how can I navigate to application's particular activity via click of webpage button's click?

Comment: Were you unable to navigate to activity as you mentioned in question? If not, please have a look @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/9194012/1496502

Answer (score 0):

Form with name `refer_now` would be assigned to the same property of global object `window`.

It mean that `refer_now` in `onclick="refer_now.performClick();"` was the form element.

**The Key is make sure that the name of `form` and the `javascriptinterface` name are different.**

Here is a solution: keep the java code and change the html with following:

```
  <form method="post" name="refer_now_form">
    <div class="refer-now-button">
      <!-- <button type="submit" class="refer-now-btn" id="refer-now">refer now</button> -->
      <input type="submit" class="refer-now-btn" value="refer now" name="refernow" id="refernow" onclick="refer_now.performClick();" />
    </div>
  </form>

 <form method="post" name="refer_now_footer_form">
    <div class="refer-now-button">
      <!-- <button type="submit" class="refer-now-btn" id="refer_now_footer">refer now</button> -->
       <input type="submit" class="refer-now-btn" value="refer now" name="refer-footer" id="refer-footer" onclick="refer_now_footer.performClick1();" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: How can I achieve this

Comment: KEY line `<form method="post" name="refer_now_form">`. Your code was `<form method="post" name="refer_now">`. The name attributes are different

Comment: So I need to write "form" in every button's name field?

Comment: Just make sure the `name` of form and the second parameter in `view.addJavascriptInterface` call are not same.

Comment: Please write java code in your answer and also js code

Comment: So that I can apply code and mark as well as check your answer